# Phaser: tilemap & set Not working at all

Tags: javascript, netbeans, phaser-framework

Here is all my code: http://pastebin.com/PmjGwQaL

Here is the new .json level: http://pastebin.com/i6W0XKbr

I currently have the tileset working fine with the old tilemap, but once i switch them over to a newly updated one it just shows a black screen.

This is the error it is giving me when i put the new tilemap in:

`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined (15:40:30:720 | error, javascript)

```
at b.TilemapLayer.render (public_html/phaser.min.js:16:25747)
at b.TilemapLayer.postUpdate (public_html/phaser.min.js:16:22169)
at b.Group.postUpdate (public_html/phaser.min.js:7:21501)
at b.Stage.postUpdate (public_html/phaser.min.js:7:11137)
at b.Game.update (public_html/phaser.min.js:8:10373)
at b.RequestAnimationFrame.updateRAF (public_html/phaser.min.js:12:7806)
at window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop (public_html/phaser.min.js:12:7700)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: i can't really check it right now, but you should use the non-minified version of phaser when developing. That way it may be easier to spot where exactly is the error. **Edit** Have you tried it with just layer1?

Comment: No I believe it is because my .json has letters instead of numbers, while my collision is looking for numbers.. but im not sure how to set it to look for letters instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `addTilesetImage()` requires two arguments. The first one is the name of the property `tilesets.name` of your json. It's basically the name you gave when imported the spritesheet in Tiled, if you used it. 
The second is the cache key of the actual image. 
So, i think, it should be `mymap.addTilesetImage('test-tileset','test-tileset');`

Moreover, "layer2" and "layer3" may have some issues because there are strange values in the data section. Maybe there are some missing images, because values like "2147483650" seem strange to me.